# showing html data in small screen using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I dont really know how to explain exactly what function i need but ill give an example.
If you try to ask a question in this forum it shows an already asked questions.
When you mouse over them its shows the content of the question that her title has been 
mouse overed on.
I want to know what html code or Jquery function can do that.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" title="I am link">Link</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/98xAL/

Comment: thanks a lot !!
do u know maybe how to implament this on FullCalendar event?

Comment: Please add a link of FullCalendar - I will check

Answer (score 0):

I personally like a lot [Coda Bubble](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-bubble.html), the tutorial is [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/), in video. Is very easy to implement and have a good design.